# 150 pages in one month

Tags: soft-question, several-complex-variables

I am a PhD student in several complex variables. My advisor wants me to study [Forstneric's "Stein manifold and holomorphic mappings"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319610573) from page 100 to page 250; I have one month. I have never attended a differential geometry class.
I have never been into such a situation; I was always used to prepare exams in a very detailed way, which is clearly impossible in this situation.

Do you have any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: My advice is to read the book in a "big picture first" style. Don't read linearly. Learn the key definitions and understand the meaning of the key theorems. Try to get a big picture view of how the material fits together. Only later learn to prove the key theorems, but perhaps skip the more difficult proofs in the early stages. Truly mastering those 150 pages could take much longer than a month, but you can still get in the game in that time frame.

Comment: Talk to your advisor! Tell her or him that you feel that you need to start with a more accessible text on differential geometry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ravi Vakil has made some interesting comments about learning math:

"...mathematics is so rich and infinite that it is impossible to
learn it systematically, and if you wait to master one topic
before moving on to the next, you’ll never get anywhere.
Instead, you’ll have tendrils of knowledge extending far from your comfort zone. Then you can later backfill from these tendrils, and extend your comfort zone; this is much easier to do than learning 'forwards'."

Later, Ravi states:

"A subtle leap is required from undergraduate thinking to
active research (even if you have done undergraduate research). Think explicitly about the process, and talk about
it (with me, and with others). For example, in an undergraduate class any Ph.D. student at Stanford will have tried
to learn absolutely all the material flawlessly. But in order to
know everything needed to tackle an important problem on
the frontier of human knowledge, one would have to spend
years reading many books and articles. So you’ll have to
learn differently. But how?"